# If $\mu(\mathrm{d}x)=e^x\nu(\mathrm{d}x)$ does $\nu(\mathrm{d}x)=e^{-x}\mu(\mathrm{d}x)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\nu$ a measure and define $\mu(\mathrm{d}x)=e^x\nu(\mathrm{d}x)$. Do we have that $$\nu(\mathrm{d}x)=e^{-x}\mu(\mathrm{d}x)\ \ ?$$
I have the impression that it's wrong and require a sort of substitution. I would rather say something as $\nu(\mathrm{d}x)=\frac{1}{x}\mu(\mathrm{d}x)$ should be more true (because if $\mathrm{d}y=e^x\mathrm{d}x$ then $\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{y}\mathrm{d}y$), but I'm not really sure how to do. Any idea ?

Comment: How about writing down the definitions of the things in your equation?  Of course you can prove nothing about them unless they have definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\nu(dx) = e^{-x} \underbrace{e^x \nu(dx)}_{\mu(dx)} = e^{-x} \, \mu(dx). \tag{1}$$ Equivalently,  $$\nu(B) = \int 1_B(x) \, \nu(dx) = \int 1_B(x) e^{-x} e^x \, \nu(dx) \stackrel{(\ast)}{=} \int 1_B(x) e^{-x} \, \mu(dx) \tag{2}$$ for any measurable set $B$. Note that $(1)$ is just a short-hand for (2). If you are not feeling sure about calculating with differentials, then write the equations down using integrals.

Note that the identity marked with $(\star)$ is not obvious; it's something you need to show: If a measure $\nu$ has a density, say $f$, with respect to a measure $\mu$, then $$\int h(x) \, d\nu(x) = \int h(x) f(x) \, d\mu(x)$$ for any "nice" function $h$ ("nice" meaning measurable and integrable w.r.t. to $\nu$).

Comment: At the end, when I set $dy=e^xdx$ I don't define an new absolute continuous measure w.r.t. the lebesgue measure $dx$ ? (because it's not true that $dy=e^xdx\implies dx=e^{-x}dy$, right ?

Comment: @user659895: There is no Lebesgue measure involved, no change of variables. You are confounding two different concepts. Changing variables involves pushing the measure (or rather, the volume form) from one manifold to another. Replacing a measure with an absolutely continuous one is just scaling, without changing the domain.

Comment: @user659895, It is indeed true that $dy=e^x\,dx$ implies $dx=e^{-x}\,dy$. (Both in measure sense and in differential-form sense.)

Comment: @user659895   You should prove the claim in $\ast$ to see what is going on. Substitution is a different concept, and refers to the [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Definition)
Interestingly, the proofs of these formulas  follow easily from the same usual procedure: it's true for characteristic functions, hence for  simple functions then use the convergence theorems. After all, they are the reasons why the Lebesgue theory is so flexible.